# Sending base64 string using Okhttp3

Tags: android, okhttp

I try to send a bitmap captured from camera like below code:

```
Object[] params = (Object[]) ev.data;
String userId = (String) params[0];
String accessKey = (String) params[1];
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) params[2];

String url = getResources().getString(R.string.url_base) + getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.url_send_photo) + userId + ""
                        + "/photo?type=ID_CARD";

OkHttpClient client = getNewHttpClient();
MediaType image = MediaType.parse("image/png");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(image, AppUtil.bitmapToBase64String(bitmap));
Request req = new Request.Builder().url(url)
          .addHeader("X-Bayarind-Access", accessKey)
          .addHeader("Content-Type", "image/png")
          .addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64")
          .post(body).build();

Response res = client.newCall(req).execute();
if (res.isSuccessful()) {
       // DO SOMETHING
} else {
       String resp = res.body().string();
       log.info(">>> RESP: " + resp);
}
```

Method **AppUtil.bitmapToBase64String** is like below:

```
public static String bitmapToBase64String(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Method **getNewHttpClient()** is like below

```
private OkHttpClient getNewHttpClient() throws Exception {
    TrustManager[] trustManagers = {new CustTrustManager()};
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sslContext.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    builder.sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
    return builder.build();
}
```

And I always receives below ERROR:

```
"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"Illegal base64 character a"
```

Can anybody point me where did I made mistakes?

Comment: Where are you sending this to? How is the server processing the base64 string?

Comment: A java spring application, another developer who built this app for IOS managed to submit cleanly. That means something wrong with my code